# How can I search within someone's Twitter followers?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to find all users that describe themselves as a "professor" within their Twitter profiles, but only if they follow certain accounts.

I've looked at [Tweet Reports](http://tweetreports.com/) but I believe this tool only allows you to search within your own followers. You can see another account's followers and do CTRL + F, but if they have thousands of followers you don't get everyone.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tweepi.com/ let's you see all of the followers of a particular account and, you can choose to see their bios in the table as well - it's not much better than the Tweet Report, *except* that you can filter on text in the bio - the screenshot shows me filtering on the keyword 'phd'

[image]

(I just discovered this while looking around to answer your question - is really useful actually when trying to remember the handle of a particular follower you want to contact... )