# How do I search within a Twitter list?

Tags: twitter

That is, I have created a Twitter list with some 100 members and would like to search for a particular word within all users of the list.

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but you could export or copy the list as csv and add them all to the advanced search [How do I search for a specific word in all tweets from a given twitter account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45209/search-for-a-specific-word-in-all-tweets-for-a-given-twitter-account)

Comment: it sounds like complicated

Answer (score 32):

Use the search string:

```
query list:username/listname
```

So for instance:

```
bowie list:twitter/media
```

https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=bowie%20list%3Atwitter%2Fmedia

If it's a private list, use the list ID (in the URL when viewing the list) instead of username/listname:

```
query list:1234567890
```

Comment: apparently, this only works for public lists. You cannot use it with your private lists.

Comment: @wisbucky You can use the list ID if it's a private list; added clarification to answer. Thanks!

Comment: Private list search doesn't seem to work, at least not via Twitter's Developer API.  I took the ID from my private list, and trying to search in the web browser for twitter.com works fine.  However, in the API, it doesn't return any results.

Comment: thanks @Jay! Yes, the list ID works for private lists (provided you are logged in, which makes sense).

Comment: Thank you! This helped with solving the list search issue on TweetDeck. I used to search through private lists with the first method as if they were public. It used to work but after some time it didn't. I tried your solution for private lists and it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the answer I literally just gave at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45443/10707, but it's still relevent....

http://www.tweepi.com/ let's you see all of the members of a public list and, you can choose to see their bios in the table as well - more importantly you can filter on text in the bio - the screenshot shows me filtering on the keyword 'phd'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TweetDeck has an option to filter by lists.

[image: TweetDeck search by list]

Comment: Please provide instructions on how to do this. Just giving an app name isn't very constructive.

Comment: @AndrewLott should be self-explanatory now. Hope it helps.